# woocommerce on order complete custom notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Woocommerce on order complete send email to a current login user if user role is subscriber.

need 3 input fields in wordpress dashboard, from where i can easily insert text in email.

```
input text field => Johannesburg,
input text field2 => Monday,
input text field3 => 12:30 PM 



Example Email:

Your test will be held at {input text field} on day {input text field2} and time {input text field3}
```

Comment: here is the email which i want to send on order complete with ability to insert date, time and location from admin area

Dear {name}

You have selected {order_name} and are now officially parter. We have scheduled an exciting in-person training session for you 

{date} at {time}. The training session will be held at {time}. A map to the location is available on the link below to facilitate you in reaching the venue conveniently on time. 

{(Location map link/image here)}

Comment: in short i want to add a custom woocommerce notification, with some term and condition as i mentioned above

Comment: yeah now please review my question

Comment: user will type manually from dashboard for 3 custom fields